# Solving MINLP with PYOMO/PYSP

Tags: optimization, pyomo

team,

currently I am working on a nonlinear stochastic optimization problem. So far, the toolbox has been really helpful, thank you! However, adding a nonlinear constraint has caused an error. I use the gurobi solver. The problem results from the following constraint.

```
def max_pcr_power_rule(model, t):
    if t == 0:
        return 0 <= battery.P_bat_max-model.P_sc_max[t+1]-model.P_pcr
    else:       
        return model.P_trade_c[t+1] + np.sqrt(-2*np.log(rob_opt.max_vio)) \
        *sum(model.U_max_pow[t,i]**2 for i in set_sim.tme_dat_stp)**(0.5) \
        <= battery.P_bat_max-model.P_sc_max[t+1]-model.P_pcr
model.max_pcr_power = Constraint(set_sim.tme_dat_stp, rule=max_pcr_power_rule)
```

I receive this error message:

> Initializing extensive form algorithm for stochastic programming
>   problems. Exception encountered. Scenario tree manager attempting to
>   shut down. Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\theil\Anaconda3\Scripts\runef-script.py", line 5, in
>   
>       sys.exit(pyomo.pysp.ef_writer_script.main())   File "C:\Users\theil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\pysp\ef_writer_script.py",
>   line 863, in main
>       traceback=options.traceback)   File "C:\Users\theil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\pysp\util\misc.py",
>   line 344, in launch_command
>       rc = command(options, *cmd_args, **cmd_kwds)   File "C:\Users\theil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\pysp\ef_writer_script.py",
>   line 748, in runef
>       ef.solve()   File "C:\Users\theil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\pysp\ef_writer_script.py",
>   line 430, in solve
>       **solve_kwds)   File "C:\Users\theil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\parallel\manager.py",
>   line 122, in queue
>       return self._perform_queue(ah, *args, **kwds)   File "C:\Users\theil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\parallel\local.py",
>   line 59, in _perform_queue
>       results = opt.solve(*args, **kwds)   File "C:\Users\theil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py",
>   line 599, in solve
>       self._presolve(*args, **kwds)   File "C:\Users\theil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\solvers\plugins\solvers\GUROBI.py",
>   line 224, in _presolve
>       ILMLicensedSystemCallSolver._presolve(self, *args, **kwds)   File "C:\Users\theil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\solver\shellcmd.py",
>   line 196, in _presolve
>       OptSolver._presolve(self, *args, **kwds)   File "C:\Users\theil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py",
>   line 696, in _presolve
>       **kwds)   File "C:\Users\theil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py",
>   line 767, in _convert_problem
>       **kwds)   File "C:\Users\theil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\convert.py",
>   line 110, in convert_problem
>       problem_files, symbol_map = converter.apply(*tmp, **tmpkw)   File "C:\Users\theil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\solvers\plugins\converter\model.py",
>   line 96, in apply
>       io_options=io_options)   File "C:\Users\theil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\block.py",
>   line 1681, in write
>       io_options)   File "C:\Users\theil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\repn\plugins\cpxlp.py",
>   line 176, in **call**
>       include_all_variable_bounds=include_all_variable_bounds)   File "C:\Users\theil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\repn\plugins\cpxlp.py",
>   line 719, in _print_model_LP
>       "with nonlinear terms." % (constraint_data.name)) ValueError: Cannot write legal LP file.  Constraint '1.max_pcr_power[1]' has a
>   body with nonlinear terms.

I thought, that the problem may lay within the nested formulation of the constraint, i.e. the combination of sum and exponential terms. Therefore, I put the sum()-term into a separate variable. This didn't change the core the characteristic of the nonlinear constraint, so that the error stayed the same. My other suspicion was, that the problem lays within the gurobi solver. So i tried to utilize ipopt, which produced the follwing error message:

> Error evaluating constraint 1: can't evaluate pow'(0,0.5). ERROR:
>   Solver (ipopt) returned non-zero return code (1) ERROR: See the solver
>   log above for diagnostic information. Exception encountered. Scenario
>   tree manager attempting to shut down. Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File "C:\Users\theil\Anaconda3\Scripts\runef-script.py", line
>   5, in 
>       sys.exit(pyomo.pysp.ef_writer_script.main())   File "C:\Users\theil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\pysp\ef_writer_script.py",
>   line 863, in main
>       traceback=options.traceback)   File "C:\Users\theil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\pysp\util\misc.py",
>   line 344, in launch_command
>       rc = command(options, *cmd_args, **cmd_kwds)   File "C:\Users\theil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\pysp\ef_writer_script.py",
>   line 748, in runef
>       ef.solve()   File "C:\Users\theil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\pysp\ef_writer_script.py",
>   line 434, in solve
>       **solve_kwds)   File "C:\Users\theil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\parallel\manager.py",
>   line 122, in queue
>       return self._perform_queue(ah, *args, **kwds)   File "C:\Users\theil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\parallel\local.py",
>   line 59, in _perform_queue
>       results = opt.solve(*args, **kwds)   File "C:\Users\theil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py",
>   line 626, in solve
>       "Solver (%s) did not exit normally" % self.name) pyutilib.common._exceptions.ApplicationError: Solver (ipopt) did not
>   exit normally

I am wondering now, if my mistake lays within the formulation of the constraint or the way i utilize the solver. Otherwise I have to simplify my problem to make it solvable.

I would be glad, if you can point me in the right direction. Thank you!

Best regards
Philipp

Comment: Gurobi can only handle linear problems (and some quadratic problems).

Comment: The ipopt error is related to not being able to evaluate the gradient of the pow function at zero. Usually this can be solved by setting a small lower bound on the corresponding x variable. In your case you have an expression, so introduce a new variable and equality constraint so you can apply this bound.

Answer (score 0):

As Erwin mentioned in the comment, Gurobi is generally not intended for nonlinear problems.